# SQLite on IONIC "TypeError: Cannot call method 'openDatabase' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Im new with IONIC and I need help on using ngCordova. I am able to create database on my app.js. But I always get this error message when trying to access the database on my controller. **"TypeError: Cannot call method 'openDatabase' of undefined"**

Below is my codes:

Controller.js:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', 'LoginService', '$ionicPopup', '$state','$cordovaSQLite',
function ($scope,LoginService,$ionicPopup, $state,$cordovaSQLite) {

$scope.data = {};

$scope.login = function() {
    var db = null;
    console.log("LOGIN user: " + $scope.data.username + " - PW: " + $scope.data.password);
    LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).success(function(data) {
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("guards.db");

                       var query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS incident_list (id integer autoincrement primary key, complainant string , defendant string, details string, remarks string,incident_date datetime)";
                        runQuery(query,[],function(res) {
                          console.log("table created done");
                        }, function (err) {
                            console.log("table created done");
                          console.log(err);
                        });
        $state.go('guardTrack.home');
    }).error(function(data) {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Login failed!',
            template: 'Please check your credentials!'
        });
    });
}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

> Check the plugin usage in ngCordova docs you include the sqlite in your controller in order to use it.

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {
  var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" });
```

> // for opening a background db:

```
var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db", bgType: 1 });
  $scope.execute = function() {
   var query = "INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, ["test",       100]).then(function(res) {
      console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId);
    }, function (err) {
      console.error(err);
   });
  };
});
```

help [Link](http://:http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=61&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1474907865&sig=AKOVD65DiJB3gp-DWqfzQLUPGiwzYWeAAw)